# r Finding a match based on age and sex

Tags: r, search, matching

I have a dataset with these columns

```
 ID    Cancer.Date    Age   Gender   Col1     Col2  
 15    1998-03-26     35    F        Yes       No
 53    NA             65    F        No        Yes
 37    1996-11-10     84    M        Yes       No
 58    NA             90    F        Yes       No
 60    2016-12-08     70    M        Yes       No
 12    2000-04-29     20    M        No        Yes
 46    NA             72    F        Yes       No
 59    2008-05-26     34    F        Yes       No
 99    NA             89    M        Yes       No
 46    2009-06-22     87    M        No        Yes
 35    2000-02-20     24    F        Yes       Yes
 26    NA             80    F        Yes       No
 43    2001-02-20     74    M        No        No
 77    NA             81    F        No        Yes
 16    2015-11-03     52    F        No        Yes
 04    NA             27    M        Yes       No
 82    2004-05-08     45    M        No        No
 01    2006-04-25     49    F        No        Yes
 92    2004-10-26     40    F        Yes       Yes
 67    2002-09-20     67    F        No        No
```

My goal is to perform the following tasks.

**Step1:** Arrange the Cancer.Date column in ascending order. Earliest date on top.  This case row with date `1996-11-10`

**Step2:** Check if the date is NA. If the date is **not NA**, then find 3 observations that are similar to that row in Gender and closest in Age.

For example, after sorting by date (earliest first), the third row will be the 1st row. The  `Gender = M, Age = 84`. So the three IDs that similar in gender and closest in Age are , (ID 46, Gender =M, Age = 87), (ID 99, Gender =M, Age = 89), (ID 43, Gender =M, Age = 74).

**Step3:** Repeat Step2 for all rows where Cancer.Date is not NA (Not Missing).

The expected Output

```
 ID    Cancer.Date    Age   Gender   Col1     Col2  Match.ID 
 37    1996-11-10     84    M        Yes       No   46,99,43
 15    1998-03-26     35    F        Yes       No   59,35,12
 .     .              .     .        .         .    .
```

Perhaps I could do this using for-loops, subset by Gender and distance by age but I suspect this would be painfully slow. I would appreciate any suggestions on accomplishing this more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `purr::map` to make this work.

```r
library(tidyverse)
read.table(textConnection("ID    Cancer.Date    Age   Gender   Col1     Col2  
                          15    1998-03-26     35    F        Yes       No
                          53    NA             65    F        No        Yes
                          37    1996-11-10     84    M        Yes       No
                          58    NA             90    F        Yes       No
                          60    2016-12-08     70    M        Yes       No
                          12    2000-04-29     20    M        No        Yes
                          46    NA             72    F        Yes       No
                          59    2008-05-26     34    F        Yes       No
                          99    NA             89    M        Yes       No
                          46    2009-06-22     87    M        No        Yes
                          35    2000-02-20     24    F        Yes       Yes
                          26    NA             80    F        Yes       No
                          43    2001-02-20     74    M        No        No
                          77    NA             81    F        No        Yes
                          16    2015-11-03     52    F        No        Yes
                          04    NA             27    M        Yes       No
                          82    2004-05-08     45    M        No        No
                          01    2006-04-25     49    F        No        Yes
                          92    2004-10-26     40    F        Yes       Yes
                          67    2002-09-20     67    F        No        No"), header = T) %>% 
  as_tibble() -> df
df
#> # A tibble: 20 x 6
#>       ID Cancer.Date   Age Gender Col1  Col2 
#>    <int> <chr>       <int> <chr>  <chr> <chr>
#>  1    15 1998-03-26     35 F      Yes   No   
#>  2    53 <NA>           65 F      No    Yes  
#>  3    37 1996-11-10     84 M      Yes   No   
#>  4    58 <NA>           90 F      Yes   No   
#>  5    60 2016-12-08     70 M      Yes   No   
#>  6    12 2000-04-29     20 M      No    Yes  
#>  7    46 <NA>           72 F      Yes   No   
#>  8    59 2008-05-26     34 F      Yes   No   
#>  9    99 <NA>           89 M      Yes   No   
#> 10    46 2009-06-22     87 M      No    Yes  
#> 11    35 2000-02-20     24 F      Yes   Yes  
#> 12    26 <NA>           80 F      Yes   No   
#> 13    43 2001-02-20     74 M      No    No   
#> 14    77 <NA>           81 F      No    Yes  
#> 15    16 2015-11-03     52 F      No    Yes  
#> 16     4 <NA>           27 M      Yes   No   
#> 17    82 2004-05-08     45 M      No    No   
#> 18     1 2006-04-25     49 F      No    Yes  
#> 19    92 2004-10-26     40 F      Yes   Yes  
#> 20    67 2002-09-20     67 F      No    No

df %>% 
  mutate(Cancer.Date = Cancer.Date %>% lubridate::as_date()) %>% 
  arrange(Cancer.Date) -> df1

df1
#> # A tibble: 20 x 6
#>       ID Cancer.Date   Age Gender Col1  Col2 
#>    <int> <date>      <int> <chr>  <chr> <chr>
#>  1    37 1996-11-10     84 M      Yes   No   
#>  2    15 1998-03-26     35 F      Yes   No   
#>  3    35 2000-02-20     24 F      Yes   Yes  
#>  4    12 2000-04-29     20 M      No    Yes  
#>  5    43 2001-02-20     74 M      No    No   
#>  6    67 2002-09-20     67 F      No    No   
#>  7    82 2004-05-08     45 M      No    No   
#>  8    92 2004-10-26     40 F      Yes   Yes  
#>  9     1 2006-04-25     49 F      No    Yes  
#> 10    59 2008-05-26     34 F      Yes   No   
#> 11    46 2009-06-22     87 M      No    Yes  
#> 12    16 2015-11-03     52 F      No    Yes  
#> 13    60 2016-12-08     70 M      Yes   No   
#> 14    53 NA             65 F      No    Yes  
#> 15    58 NA             90 F      Yes   No   
#> 16    46 NA             72 F      Yes   No   
#> 17    99 NA             89 M      Yes   No   
#> 18    26 NA             80 F      Yes   No   
#> 19    77 NA             81 F      No    Yes  
#> 20     4 NA             27 M      Yes   No

closest <- function(x, df = df1){
  if(is.na(x)){
    NA
    } else{
      df1 %>% 
        filter(Cancer.Date == x) -> s_row 
      df1 %>% 
        filter((Gender == s_row$Gender & !Cancer.Date == x) %>% replace_na(T)) %>% 
        pull(Age) %>% 
        enframe(name = NULL) %>% 
        mutate(num = s_row$Age,
               diff = abs(num-value)) %>% 
        arrange(diff) %>% 
        slice(1:3) %>% 
        pull(value) -> near_ages
      df1 %>% 
        filter(Age %in% near_ages & Gender == s_row$Gender) %>% 
        pull(ID) %>% 
        paste(collapse = ",")
    }
}

df1 %>% 
  mutate(Match.ID = Cancer.Date %>% map_chr(closest))
#> # A tibble: 20 x 7
#>       ID Cancer.Date   Age Gender Col1  Col2  Match.ID
#>    <int> <date>      <int> <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr>   
#>  1    37 1996-11-10     84 M      Yes   No    43,46,99
#>  2    15 1998-03-26     35 F      Yes   No    35,92,59
#>  3    35 2000-02-20     24 F      Yes   Yes   15,92,59
#>  4    12 2000-04-29     20 M      No    Yes   82,60,4 
#>  5    43 2001-02-20     74 M      No    No    37,46,60
#>  6    67 2002-09-20     67 F      No    No    53,46,26
#>  7    82 2004-05-08     45 M      No    No    12,60,4 
#>  8    92 2004-10-26     40 F      Yes   Yes   15,1,59 
#>  9     1 2006-04-25     49 F      No    Yes   15,92,16
#> 10    59 2008-05-26     34 F      Yes   No    15,35,92
#> 11    46 2009-06-22     87 M      No    Yes   37,43,99
#> 12    16 2015-11-03     52 F      No    Yes   92,1,53 
#> 13    60 2016-12-08     70 M      Yes   No    37,43,46
#> 14    53 NA             65 F      No    Yes   <NA>    
#> 15    58 NA             90 F      Yes   No    <NA>    
#> 16    46 NA             72 F      Yes   No    <NA>    
#> 17    99 NA             89 M      Yes   No    <NA>    
#> 18    26 NA             80 F      Yes   No    <NA>    
#> 19    77 NA             81 F      No    Yes   <NA>    
#> 20     4 NA             27 M      Yes   No    <NA>
```

if you want to increase the efficiency you can look into `furrr` package which will make the code run in parallel.

<sup>Created on 2021-01-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>